How do I draw a path based object in swiftui
When I draw a manual object I get a rect but the fill of the object spills into the canvas.  When I use Gesture to collect the path information it doesn't draw at all.
ZStack {
    let newObject = DrawingObject(
        tool: Tools.square,
        points: [CGPoint(x: 72.0, y: 72.0), CGPoint(x: 144.0, y: 144.0)],
        penThickness: 2,
        penColor: .purple,
        fillColor: .green
    )
    Objects.draw(newObject, in:geometry.size)
        
    Path { path in
        for curObj in dm.objects {
            Objects.draw( curObj, in: geometry.size )
        }
    }
}

Here is the draw code:
static func draw(_ object: DrawingObject, in size: CGSize) -> some View {
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = min(size.width, size.height)
    var myObj =  Path { path in
        path.addPath(createPath(for: object.tool, with: object.points, scaleFactor: scaleFactor))
    }
    .stroke(lineWidth: object.penThickness)
    .foregroundColor(object.penColor)
    .background(object.fillColor ?? Color.clear)
    return myObj
}

This is the textual results from my debugging.  Both objects look pretty much the same other than the objects coordinates and color.
CP is the object type requested.  
SF is the scale factor (I have turned off all scale calculations. 
P is the the points stored in my DrawingObject struct.

Manual object
CP: square SF: 3000.0 P: [(72.0, 72.0), (144.0, 144.0)] 2
    Rect: (72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0)
    Path: ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<_StrokedShape<Path>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _BackgroundStyleModifier<Color>>(content: SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI._StrokedShape<SwiftUI.Path>, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<SwiftUI.Color>>>(content: SwiftUI._StrokedShape<SwiftUI.Path>(shape: 72 72 m 144 72 l 144 144 l 72 144 l h,                                     style: SwiftUI.StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0, lineCap: __C.CGLineCap, lineJoin: __C.CGLineJoin, miterLimit: 10.0, dash: [], dashPhase: 0.0)), modifier: SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<SwiftUI.Color>>(keyPath: \EnvironmentValues.<computed 0x00000001b7bf9c1c (Optional<Color>)>, value: Optional(purple))), modifier: SwiftUI._BackgroundStyleModifier<SwiftUI.Color>(style: green, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: SwiftUI.Edge.Set(rawValue: 15)))

Dynamic object
CP: square SF: 3000.0 P: [(70.0234375, 143.31640625), (141.921875, 214.16796875)] 2
    Rect: (70.0234375, 143.31640625, 71.8984375, 70.8515625)
    Path: ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<_StrokedShape<Path>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, _BackgroundStyleModifier<Color>>(content: SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI._StrokedShape<SwiftUI.Path>, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<SwiftUI.Color>>>(content: SwiftUI._StrokedShape<SwiftUI.Path>(shape: 70.0234 143.316 m 141.922 143.316 l 141.922 214.168 l 70.0234 214.168 l h, style: SwiftUI.StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0, lineCap: __C.CGLineCap, lineJoin: __C.CGLineJoin, miterLimit: 10.0, dash: [], dashPhase: 0.0)), modifier: SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<SwiftUI.Color>>(keyPath: \EnvironmentValues.<computed 0x00000001b7bf9c1c (Optional<Color>)>, value: Optional(black))), modifier: SwiftUI._BackgroundStyleModifier<SwiftUI.Color>(style: blue, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: SwiftUI.Edge.Set(rawValue: 15)))


Edit - 1
I have another clue.  I can use the objects list directly like this and it draws to the screen.  I changed my draw function to return a path to accomplish this.
if( dm.objects.count > 0) {
    Objects.draw( dm.objects[0], in: geometry.size )
        .fill( dm.objects[0].fillColor ?? .clear )
        .stroke(dm.objects[0].penColor, lineWidth: newObject.penThickness)
}

Not sure if any of this is correct way to do this in SwiftUI.  When I still had a path I tried returning the path or setting a variable with the result of the draw function and returning that.  None of that worked.  Kind of running out of ideas.
